# AFNetworking takes 60 seconds to return with a 401 status code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I have an iOS application using AFNetworking for the network calls. Everything works great except when I am trying to capture a 401 status code. It always takes about 60 seconds for the call to return with a response. Is there any setting or something that would cause this? Every successful call returns instantly. I have also tried running this code through curl and the 401 returns instantly. Here is the code I am using:

```
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        __weak AFHTTPRequestOperation *_operation = operation;

        [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
                    //It takes 60 seconds to get to this line if a 401 is encountered
            DDLogInfo(@"Response body: %@", [_operation responseString]);

            if(_operation.response.statusCode == 401) {
                DDLogInfo(@"Expired Auth Token");
            }

            NSError *error = [_operation error];        
            NSData *responseData = [_operation responseData];

            if(responseData == nil && error == nil)
                error = [NSError errorWithDomain:isDevMode ? DEV_SERVICE_BASE_URL : SERVICE_BASE_URL code:-1 userInfo:nil];

            callback(error, responseData);
        }];

        [operation start];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your NSURLRequest with a timeout value that fits your needs.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:inURL 
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad 
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
```

See the [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Then, initialize AFNetworking's `AFHTTPRequestOperation` with that initialized `NSMutableURLRequest` request.

Comment: Alright I'll try that. But I am still confused why this would be a timeout at all? It should return instantly with a 401 because the server is responding but with an error status code. How can I get it to return instantly without messing with the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

When the request fails with the code 401, the failure block of the operation is called, which you haven't set. Use the following method of AFHTTPRequestOperation for your operation and the failure block will be called instantaneously.

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                              failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

Sorry, didn't notice this thread was 6 months old! Anyhow, for those who are still facing the problem, the answer remains.

Comment: can you please give an example on how to use this?

Comment: Read this, it is pretty self-explanatory -> http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html#//api/name/setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:
A quick search on github gave this good example -> https://github.com/poeks/TwitterTest/blob/0f46c3c882e036d19007723d6dca74f3d2561f67/TwitterTest/Networky.m
Hope it helps..